# How to implement theme on a data bound list control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a `ListBox` data bound to an `ObservableCollection<Employee>`. It is working well. I need to change the FontFamily and FontSize based on user setting in `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings`. Can anyone suggest the best design pattern for a situation such as this? I am trying to avoid doing this in C# code behind. It would be better if I can bind the FontSize and FontFamily properties in the `ListBox` data template to the values in the `ApplicationSettings`. Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the FontFamily and FontSize into your ViewModel, as properties, and bind to them.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should have `FontSize` and `FontFamily` properties in my ViewModel which is an `ObservableCollection<Employee>`? Or should the properties be in the Employee class itself? If you are referring to the latter, I know how to create the binding expression but I thought that was not an ideal solution (does not seem right to mix `FontSize` with Employee data). If you are referring to the former, how should the binding expression look like. (The Listbox's ItemSource is set to the instance of the ViewModel.) I am afraid, my understanding of XAML binding is not very good.

Comment: I would recommend moving this OC to a property of the ViewModel and adding font size and fontfamily as additional properties. Everything your view needs should be in the viewmodel, including these parameters...

Comment: As Chris says, you misunderstood the idea with ViewModels, if you use a Collection as your datacontext.

Comment: I was able to implement the code per your suggestions. It makes more sense this way. Thanks.